# Question on Finding Coordinates in Terms of Orthogonal Bases

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Find the coordinates of the standard basis vectors $e_1, e_2$, and $e_3$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in terms of the orthogonal basis of:

$$v_1= \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} \qquad v_2= \begin{bmatrix}1+\sqrt{3}\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix} \qquad v_3= \begin{bmatrix}1-\sqrt{3}\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

I know it's a simple question, I'm not too familiar with orthogonal bases and was assuming there was a simple procedure for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $$e_1=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3$$ so that $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ is the coordinates of $e_1$ in terms of $v_1, v_2, v_3$. Then because of orthogonality of $v_i$s we can take scalar product on both sides w.r.t. $v_1, v_2$ and $v_3$ respectively to get $$ a_1=\frac{e_1\cdot v_1}{v_1\cdot v_1}=\frac{0}{2}=0$$ 
$$ a_2=\frac{e_1\cdot v_2}{v_2\cdot v_2}=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{6+2\sqrt{3}}$$ 
$$ a_3=\frac{e_1\cdot v_3}{v_3\cdot v_3}=\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{6-2\sqrt{3}}$$ So $e_1$ has coordinates $$\left(0, \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{6+2\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{6-2\sqrt{3}}\right)$$ with respect to $v_1, v_2, v_3$. Similar process can be performed for $e_2$ and $e_3$.

In the absence of orthogonality, you would have to use elementary row operations to transform the matrix $[v_1\; v_2\; v_3\; :\; e_1\; e_2\; e_3]$ into the form $[e_1\; e_2\ e_3\; :\; u_1\; u_2\; u_3]$. So $u_1, u_2, u_3$ would be the coordinate vectors of $e_1, e_2, e_3$ in terms of $v_1, v_2, v_3$.